# Exception based on Not Null Constraint despite value is filled

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a UWP Applicatoin using EF Core 2.2.6 together with SQLite. I try to save an Entity called "RecurringPayment" which has a constraint that the value StartDate has to be set. I add and save it with this code:

```
        cont.RecurringPayments.Add(payment1.RecurringPayment);
        cont.SaveChanges();
```

The object `payment1.RecurringPayment` has this values right before calling `Add`:

[image]

But when `SaveChanges` is called, this exception is thrown:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException : An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
---- Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException : SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed: RecurringPayments.StartDate'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.NoopExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entries)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at MoneyFox.Application.Tests.Payments.Commands.CreatePayment.CreatePaymentCommandTests.CreatePaymentWithRecurring_PaymentSaved() in C:\Users\padruttn\Documents\git\MoneyFox.Windows\Src\MoneyFox.Application.Tests\Payments\Commands\CreatePayment\CreatePaymentCommandTests.cs:line 55
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
----- Inner Stack Trace -----
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
```

The Table has this creation SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "RecurringPayments" (
    "Id" INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_RecurringPayments" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "Amount" REAL NOT NULL,
    "CategoryId" INTEGER NULL,
    "ChargedAccountId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "EndDate" TEXT NULL,
    "IsEndless" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Note" TEXT NULL,
    "Recurrence" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "StartDate" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "TargetAccountId" INTEGER NULL,
    "Type" INTEGER NOT NULL, "CreationTime" TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0001-01-01 00:00:00', "ModificationDate" TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0001-01-01 00:00:00',
    CONSTRAINT "FK_RecurringPayments_Categories_CategoryId" FOREIGN KEY ("CategoryId") REFERENCES "Categories" ("Id") ON DELETE SET NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_RecurringPayments_Accounts_ChargedAccountId" FOREIGN KEY ("ChargedAccountId") REFERENCES "Accounts" ("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_RecurringPayments_Accounts_TargetAccountId" FOREIGN KEY ("TargetAccountId") REFERENCES "Accounts" ("Id") ON DELETE SET NULL
)
```

Do I understand that exception wrong or why does EfCore think that the value StartDate is empty when it is clearly filled on calling Add?

Answer (score 0):

Okey issue was in my  entity model. The StartDate value was defined as follows:

```
    public DateTime StartDate { get; }
```

Values where always added via the constructor. Turns out EF Core needs at least a private setter. So I had to adjust that it looks like this:

```
    public DateTime StartDate { get; private set; }
```